# how to calculate separation index value in PCA and KPCA

Tags: classification

i have problem on calculating separation index (SI) in PCA and KPCA, i have been calculated pca and kpca and got the percentage of variance from PC1 and PC2. Is it same if I use percentage variance or separation index to compare result of PCA and KPCA ? [image: result of PCA score plot]

[image: result of KPCA score plot]